# Copy Constructor with reference variable

Tags: c++

I have a class as given below, I want to write a copy constructor for the same. 
I need to create a deep copy constructor for this. following code is printing x and c properly but value of y here is garbage.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
class MyClass
{
public:

 MyClass(int a) : y(a) {
 }
 MyClass(const MyClass &myClass) : y(myClass.y)
 {
  x = myClass.x;
  c = new char[10];
  strcpy(c, myClass.c);
 }

  int x;
  char *c;
  int &y;

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 MyClass m1(0);
 m1.c = new char[10];
 strcpy(m1.c, "gourav");
 m1.x = 10;
 m1.y = m1.x;

 MyClass m2 = m1;

 printf("x=%d\nc=%s\ny=%d\n", m2.x, m2.c, m2.y);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: i didn't find garbage output using MSVC++ 2008.

Comment: Try using a string rather than char*. It would be much easier and safer.

Comment: You first constructor is very broken. I am surprised that compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, **y** is reference.. You're creating MyClass m1(0), so m1.y points to a **temporary** variable - 0. You just **must not** do this.. I don't know why you **y** member is reference.. ?? Anyway, if you want this to be that way, do that:

```
//..
int a = 10;
MyClass m1(a);
//..
```

Anyway, this is ugly.. And dangerous, if you don't know what you're actually doing.. You should really have a very good reason to do that.

Also, redesign your class, and its members' names..

So, the problem is NOT in the copy-constructor at all..

Comment: I created a local variable as you suggested and passed it to m1(a) that too didn't fixed the problem.


Also in the copy constructor when I am putting copy value like this 
y = myClass.y;
then I am getting following errors.
1>d:\working\oops.cpp\oops.cpp\oops.cpp(9) : error C2758: 'MyClass::y' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list
1>        d:\working\oops.cpp\oops.cpp\oops.cpp(19) : see declaration of 'MyClass::y'

Comment: OKay, what do you mean by that? What did you change, to see this message?

Comment: Instead of previous copy constructor definition MyClass(const MyClass &myClass) : y(myClass.y), I changed it to MyClass(const MyClass &myClass) and moved the y = myClass.y to inside the function, that introduced following errors

Comment: it's not allowed.. Why don't you just remove the ref and leave the member just int y; ? Also, you cannot redirect reference. So, m1.y = 10; will change the object, pointed by y.

Comment: As prasoon said, MyClass(const MyClass &myClass) : y(x) works and keeps the value of X but MyClass(const MyClass &myClass) : y(myClass.y) does not work and gives garbage.

Comment: It was indeed not an good idea to use y, the question of writing a copy constructor for an class with an int, pointer and reference was asked to me by an interviewer, may be he wanted to test my two skills References and Copy Constructor.
After your suggestions I figured out the mistake I was doing was passing a temporary value to a function where a reference is going to receive it.

Comment: Yes, but MyClass(const MyClass &myClass) : y(x) works, because x is a local variable (for the class), so that y points to x (which is already stored in the class). It's totally different from what you wanted to do, at least in your code. But this way, y pointing to x, which is already stored in the object, y is useless, so you could just remove it. Holding reference to a outside-object is pretty dangerous, because you could not know how long will this object exist.

Comment: That's why, making y to point x is safe, because x will live as long as your object lives. But it doesn't make any sense :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not copying, but the constructor:
MyClass(int a) : y(a) {}.
Here y is a reference to a TEMPORARY variable, which disappears..

Answer (score 3):

In your first constructor taking an int, you are referencing a temporary local variable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like your code.

The other answers pointed out why you are getting garbage value.

A better version of your code would look like this :

```
#include <iostream>
class MyClass
{

  int x;
  std::string c; //use std::string instead of char*
  int &y;

  public :

  MyClass (int a, std::string b): x(a), c(b),y(x) {}
  MyClass (const MyClass& myclass) : x (myclass.x), c(myclass.c), y(myclass.y) {}

  void print()
  {
     std::cout << x << " " << c << " " << y <<std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{

    MyClass m1 (10, "Gaurav");
    MyClass m2 = m1;

    m1.print();
    m2.print();
}
```

Output :

```
10 Gaurav 10
10 Gaurav 10
```

Comment: What has to be meant? `y` gets initialized to `x` which has already been intialized to `myclass.x`.

Comment: this way, isn't this member y useless? I meant "what do you win, putting y as a member, referencing to other member". Anyway, I was just curious (:

Comment: @Kiril : Nothin! IMHO the whole point of using `y` is useless in OP. Ok! modified the code. :)

Comment: Sorry man, I didn't mean anything bad, don't get angry, just asking. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

In your code, step of confusion is line:
m1.y = m1.x;

It looks like y gets assigned with value x, but that's not happening here. 
You are actually trying to change the value of a variable which y refers to. In your code that referred variable is a local temporary variable, which does not exist after its scope is over.
That is why you are getting garbage value once the control goes to copy ctor.